# Swagger UI with Spring Security Using SecurityFilterChain - Unauthorized error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, swagger-ui

I am using trying to implement swagger-ui using **SecurityFilterChain** in Spring-Boot.
I have tried various ways to get this working but everytime I am getting the below error.

**Unauthorized error**: Full authentication is required to access this resource

I am using springfox 3.0

Adding the code for swagger config and security config below.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    

    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
                //new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated());
                        
                        
                        
        http.cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
        
            @Override
            public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
                config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                return config;
            }
        });
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
public class SwaggerConfig {
    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "header");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo("Spring Boot ", "Spring Boot Doc", "716",
                "Terms of service", new Contact("Test", "www.xyz.com", "test@gmail.com"),
                "License of API", "API license URL", Collections.emptyList());
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext())).securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey())).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to make any progress on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is my code i  have added to my webSecurityConfiguration

```
 @Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs/**");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try web.ignoring()

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/proxy/**");
}
```

Comment: Same error :- AuthEntryPointJwt [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It was fixed when I added the following.

```
...antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-resources", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/proxy/**").permitAll()...
```

**SecurityFilterChain Bean in My Security Class**

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-resources", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/proxy/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(roleConverter);
        return http.build();
    }
```

**springdoc dependency for Swagger-UI**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>
```

If you have a different filter method(like OncePerRequestFilter) during the request, you should make sure you don't get an error there.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your SecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
            "/configuration/**",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/webjars/**");
}
```

Comment: This is the for the old version that uses WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
I am using SecurityFilterChain.